# How to open Gmail app (Not creating email just only open inbox) in url_launcher?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
mailto:<email address>?subject=<subject>&body=<body>
```

This one creates an email. I want to just open the Gmail app (inbox) with **url_launcher** package.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use

```
launch("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox")
```

This will open the inbox

Comment: Its opening the chrome browser!
I want to open the Gmail app

Comment: but you want to use the urlLauncher which open URLs in the chrome browser. Mailto works since it is specially designed in the gmail app to provide for mailto links.

Answer (score 0):

You can use external dependency to open any app or playstore directly.

https://pub.dev/packages/external_app_launcher

Comment: No I mean Is it possible to open with url_launcher package?

Comment: I doubt, there is any such URL scheme present which triggers the Gmail directly without any intent (except mailto://).

Answer (score 0):

*currently launch() is deprecated, instead use launchUrl(). below _inputController is text field controller*

```
final Uri params = Uri(
  scheme: 'mailto',
  path: 'abcd@gmail.com',
  query: 'subject=emails&body=${_inputController.text}',
);
final url = params.toString();
final urlPath = Uri.parse(url);
launchUrl(urlPath);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible with the `url_launcher` package.

To open the gmail app (inbox) with pre-filled mailto, subject and body, you can do something like this:

```dart
final Uri params = Uri(
  scheme: 'mailto',
  path: 'mailto@gmail.com',
  query: 'subject=This is the subject&body=this is body',
);
final url = params.toString();
launch(url);
```